# Remove specific white spaces from txt file

Tags: shell, sed

I have a large txt file with two columns, the two columns are separated by a lot of white space:

```
123467,       And the second part here
```

To remove the white space between the columns I used

```
sed -e "s/ /,/g" < a.txt
```

However it also removed the spaces between words in the second column

```
And the second part here
```

How can I just remove the spaces between columns without effecting the words in second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
sed -E -e 's@, +@,@'
```

This would remove space after a `,`. You should also not use g as it will try to match all pattern in the line.

Comment: You don't even need to put the comma on both sides.

Comment: He wanted to remove the space between columns, not to remove the comma. Hence, my sed script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/  *//' file
123467,And the second part here
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're thinking of the file as being columns separated by commas, it makes sense to use a tool that treats the input as columns separated by commas:

```
awk '$1=$1' OFS=, FS=', *' input
```

Comment: That would delete the whole line when $1 is 0. Don't use the result of an action as a condition unless you have a specific purpose in mind by doing so - `awk '{$1=$1}1'`.